# Flutter - [firebase_auth/notification-not-forwarded] error occurs after adding Notification Service Extension (for image in push notification)

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Using firebase phone_auth works normally until I added a Notification Service Extension (via Xcode) according to FlutterFire docs ->
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration

The verification process was not evoked, and the error shows

> [firebase_auth/notification-not-forwarded] if app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by uiapplicationdelegate need to be forwarded to firauth's canhandlenotificaton: method.

The error occurs on iOS only. I think there might be some conflict of the swizzling method with the extension.

Answer (score 0):

After going through [this thread](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9010), I found the following solution:

In your Podfile, use the following:

```
target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

In your AppDelegate, add `import Firebase` and use:

```
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    // This is the important new part:
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        super.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo, fetchCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
            completionHandler(.noData)
            return
        }
    }
}
```